# What rules do I have to follow to build a package in Composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

I want to create a simple package in *PHP composer*, but I have no idea what rules I should follow to create a standard package. I know that I should have a **public repository on GitHub** and also create a **composer.json** file, but I don't know what else should I do. Can someone give me some advice?

Comment: I don't think there are any strict "rules". What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Since it's my first time creating a package in composer, I have no idea if there are any special rules that I should follow.

Comment: Then why not start coding and see if any rules are needed? Why not look at existing packages (or Composer's documentation) to get some inspiration?

Comment: Yeah, I know, I am coding, just wanted to get some advice. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first and most important step is to think about your namespace.
Having a unique namespace is important.

Then you should follow some standards regarding Autoloading, see PSR-4

Create a "Readme" about your package und a composer.json to describe your dependencies.

Version Numbers are usually build by the tags of your git Repository, when you start with 1.0, your package should work.

See all details at https://packagist.org/

Good Luck!